# Using Laravel and Mockery

Tags: laravel, mockery

i just try to go in this :
I have a class A which uses services of class B.
To isolate this class A and to test it I would like to use Mockery and stub class B.

To do so I did

```
public function testMock()
{

    $driver = Mockery::mock('Driver');
    App::instance('Driver',$driver);
    $driver->shouldReceive('get')->once()->andReturn('Did the job');

    $request = new BSRequest($driver);

    $this->assertEquals($request->get(),'Did the job');

}
```

But i get always this message after running test
ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to BSrequest::__construct() must be an instance of Driver, instance of Mockery_0_Library_Driver given, called in /var/www/laravel/app/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 56 and defined

And my BSrequest is just this:

```
    class BSrequest {

private $driver;

public function __construct(Driver $driver) {
    $this->driver = $driver;
}

function get() {
    return $this->driver->get();
}}
```

Could you tell me how to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Does the "Driver" class actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're running into a namespacing issue OR you're running into an autoloading issue.

In your test file, ensure that the Driver class has been autoloaded. You can do something like this:

```
public function testDriverClassIsAvailable()
{

    $driver = new Driver();

    $this->assertEquals(get_class($driver), 'Driver');
}
```

If this works, then you will know that your `Driver` class is autoloaded and available and there is an issue with the `BSRequest` class because it does not have a `Driver` class available. If you're using namespaces, ensure that there are no typos.

A mocked `Driver` instance should satisfy the type-hinting required by the `BSRequest->__construct()` so you should definitely include the typehint.

Answer (score 0):

In fact every things work great when writing

```
public function __construct($driver) {
    $this->driver = $driver;
}
```

That's mean removing the Type control on $driver.
But I'm sure that we can achieve all this stuff keeping Driver $driver

Unfortunatly I'm unable to know how